# SheepShaverGUI.exe on Windows Error

Tags: emulation, mac-os-classic, sheepshaver

I am trying to install SheepShaver on Windows and when I try to open SheepShaverGUI.exe it gives me this error

`The procedure entry point pango_font_map_create_context could not be located in the dynamic link library C:\Program Files (x86)\GtkSharp\2.12\bin\libpangocairo-1.0-0.dll`

Here is what I have in the folder:

[image: In folder SheepShaver: Folder CD-ROM drivers. Folder Ethernet drivers. Folder General documents. Folder HFVExplorer. File Basiliskll_keycodes, 7 KB. File Mac_OS_ROM, 1,901 KB. File Mac_OS_ROM_oldworld, 4,096 KB. Text Document READ_ME, 1 KB. Application extension SDL.dll, 314 KB. Application SheepShaver, 912 KB. File SheepShaver_prefs, 1 KB. Application SheepShaverGUI, 122 KB. Text Document stdout, 1 KB.]

Note that I am running Windows 10 Pro x64, Build 10586

Comment: Did you install the GTK runtime?  SheepShaver requires GTK +2 and SDL run-times are installed.

Comment: Yes I have them both installed.

Comment: Emaculation has a walk-through on setting up SheepShaver you might find helpful (http://www.emaculation.com/doku.php/sheepshaver_setup).  The interesting bit is they mention newer versions of GTK may not work and recommend using version 2.10.13 (which they provide a link to).

Comment: I am following that tutorial so that is the version that I have installed

Comment: GTK apps on Windows are an adventure. I'm reminded of the term "yak shaving" which is apropos.

Comment: 32-bit or 64-bit? That might make a difference. Could you run `msinfo32` and tell us the "OS Name", "Version" and, most importantly, the "System Type" values from the System Summary?

Comment: @wizzwizz4
OS Name: Microsoft Windows 10 Pro
Version: 10.0.10586 Build 10586
System Type: x64-based PC

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Uninstall GTK +2 if you already have it. Go to [Emaculation](http://emaculation.com/doku.php/sheepshaver_setup) and download the GTK +2 Runtime from there. Set it up and SheepShaverGui.exe should work. If not, restart your computer.